# Filter Pages based on Selected Template

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have five custom pages and two custom templates, I am trying to configure three pages, in template 'A' and other two pages in template 'B'.

In Editing a page, I selected appropriate templates for all pages.

But still I end up seeing all pages in one plugin.

For template, this is the syntax which I followed:

```
/**
*Template Name: A
*/

/**
Template Name: B
*/
```

Comment: Check to see if you have files that go according to page slug.. this means if you have about-us.php it will override the page template you chose for the 'about-us' page in the dashboard. If you also have spaces in your template files name eg. 'about us.php', wordpress might not read it.

Comment: @msbodetti template files are withoutspace

and there is no file with same name, as you said about 'about-us' page

Comment: Add in an HTML comment to the templates. `<!-- template A -->` in template A and `<!-- template B -->` in template B. Then inspect your page using devtools to see if that is actually the template being used. Sounds like an inheritance issue to me.